# Error on POSTGRES SQL QUERY invalid Syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a query similar to this

```
select to_char(
    select min(date) from MyTable, 
    'YYYY-MM-DD'
);
```

But I keep getting this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2:  select min(date) from MyTable, 
     ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 18
```

Answer (score 2):

Subqueries need their own parentheses:

```
select to_char( (select min(date) from MyTable), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

This would more traditionally be written as:

```
select to_char(min(date), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
from MyTable;
```

No subquery is necessary.